# Android alertdialogue returning boolean

Tags: android

I am wring a simple script where there is a confirmation box of two options. I need to cal it more than one time in an activity. So i made a method to do that. Based on the returning boolean i want to write the conditional statements.

```
// Before oncreate

  static boolean confirmation;   





     private void showConfirmation() {
            // UserFunctions userFunctions = null;
            // TODO Auto-generated methodastub

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("test");
            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please update the unfilled fields.").setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                            confirmation = false;

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Later on", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            confirmation = true;
                        }
                    });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

    }    








  @Override
    public void myOnClickRecharge(View v) {

        showConfirmation();
        if (confirmation){ 

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That way you will always return false, because the method doesnt wait for the dialog to be closed. I suggest you use one static boolean, and change its value, according to what button is clicked. Before onCreate():

```
boolean confirmation;
```

Then in your code:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please update the unfilled fields.").setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                confirmation = false;
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Later on", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  confirmation = true;
            }
        });
```

And then you check it that way:

```
if (confirmation)
{
    //Do something (TRUE)
}
else
{   
    //Do something (FALSE)
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: But change whats inside the buttons of the dialog. Change it to become like mines.

Comment: Is it working now? If yes, please upvote/choose as an answer.